# Customizing the columns for the azure-devops backlog's board view

Tags: azure-devops

The Azure-DevOps backlog's board view, by default has the States of the Work item as the columns.
[image: VSTS Board with States as Cloumns]

Does this board view of the backlog supports the work item differentiation (columns) based on a field value of a work item?

***For EX:*** Backlog board view having columns based on the priority of the work item? ('Priority' being a field in the work item).